# Not able to update innodb_ft_num_word_optimize

Tags: mysql, optimization, amazon-rds, configuration, full-text-search

We are using a AWS-RDS(MySQL 5.7) instance with 16GB RAM. We have a table with millions of entries and a FULL-TEXT index which needs to be OPTIMIZED.

Apparently, FULL-TEXT optimization is very expensive and hence MySQL provides the variable `innodb_ft_num_word_optimize` to control the number of words that is optimized at one time. The default value of this variable is `2000`.

For some unknown reason we are not able to update this value beyond `10000`. Increasing beyond this results in the RDS instance being stuck in `Incompatible-parameter` state. In one of the other RDS instance, changing the value did not produce any error but the value of `innodb_ft_num_word_optimize` maxed out at 10000. MySQL documentation does not mention any max value for this variable.

Can someone explain this behavior ?

Comment: Suggest providing a bug to bugs.mysql.com .